# Nuxt.JS - Cannot read property 'mounted' of undefined

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js since some weeks and building local to serve as SPA on my Plesk Server. Since days I'm trying to get the CentOS 7 Server to build (first try on console).

npm Version: 6.14.8
node Version 12.4.0

The build is running, but on the page I'm geeting the following error, after trying to login:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mounted' of undefined
    at Auth.mounted (auth.js?facc:112)
    at Auth.setStrategy (auth.js?facc:108)
    at Auth.loginWith (auth.js?facc:123)
    at VueComponent.einloggen (index.vue?6ced:49)
    at submit (index.vue?4d15:20)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.common.dev.js?4650:1859)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2184)
    at HTMLFormElement.original._wrapper (vue.common.dev.js?4650:7543)
```

On my local instance I'm not getting this error and if I run the build local and deploy the generated folder, everything works fine. So I'm not shure how to fix this bug. I found out there was a problem with Facebook Login Strategy, but I'm not using this. I'm using a Custom Scheme, but extended from `LocalScheme from '@nuxtjs/auth/lib/schemes/local'` and the error I'm geeting has nothing to do with that I think.

Has Someone an idea what I can try out?

Thank you!